# How do I export a translation from WPML to use on Shopify?

Tags: woocommerce, shopify, translation, wpml

I have a WooCommerce site that has been translated using WPML. We are migrating our store to Shopify. What are the steps I need to take to export my WPML translation into a format that can be used by Shopify?

It's my understanding that Shopify will only accept CSV uploads of translation files. I was able to [export my WPML data to XLIFF](https://wpml.org/documentation/translating-your-contents/using-desktop-cat-tools/configuring-xliff-file-options/) but that doesn't seem to be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping for an option native to WPML but I ended up following this tutorial on their site that uses a 3rd party app: [Export Multilingual Websites Using WP All Export and WPML (from WPML.org)](https://wpml.org/compatibility/2016/08/export-multilingual-websites-using-wp-all-export-and-wpml/). Note, I had already imported the English version of my webpage including products and content.

I ended up using [WP Import All](https://www.wpallimport.com/export-wordpress/) with their [Product Export Add-On](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-export-for-woocommerce/). I followed the WPML tutorial exporting WooCommerce products instead of posts.

Instead of exporting by language, I exported all languages at once. The `WPML Language Code` field was very useful here since it corresponded nicely to the Shopify language codes. Here's what my customized export fields looked like:

[image: Screenshot of export fields from the WP ALL EXPORT plugin. The fields displayed are ID, Title, Content, SKU, Product Type, Parent Product ID, WPML Translation ID, WPML Language Code, and Short Description.]

Now you need to reformat the exported CSV to fit with Shopify's format. For those who've never opened CSVs with international text [I found guide this helpful](https://www.isurvey.soton.ac.uk/help/opening-csv-files-containing-international-language-data/index.html). I also wanted to [remove all the HTML](https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-HTML-Tags-in-Excel) that was exported in the product descriptions as well.

Finally, I followed their import instructions [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/markets/languages/translate#exporting-importing-translations) to upload my filled out CSV.

These instructions cover how to migrate the products. For other features of the site (web pages, categories, etc) it's either repeat these steps or copy and paste.